How to stop sponsored notifications in Facebook iOS app?
This week suddenly I’m getting new, unwanted notifications in Facebook iOS app. They do not appear in FB’s website/webapp. They say:

You might still be interested in [Sponsor’s Name]: “[Advertisement Name]…
Sponsored

Under the ellipsis menu, I am given these choices:

Hide ad – This will hide this single ad, but it will not stop the next.
Report ad – This also will not stop further notification ads.
Why am I seeing this ad? – This leads to a maze of legalese.

Any ideas on how to stop, disable, prevent, opt out of these new sponsored notifications?


If FB is misusing the notification system to push ads, you could reach out to Apple (contact forms are on apple.com).

I'm seeing the same annoying ads. At least for me, there's no push notification (though I have limited what pushes I get) but the ads show up 3rd in the view of the in-app notification list. I also find it very hard to interact with the three-dots icon to get the ad options. It feels very "dark pattern" to me.
